# SQL (SQLite) Search from table1 and update in table2

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

As in title I need search a value in table1 and update table2.

table1

```
|id | nameEN | namePL|
----------------------
|1  | Cat    | Kot   |
|2  | Cow    | Krowa |
|3  | Dog    | Pies  |
```

table2

```
|id | nameEN | namePL|
----------------------
|1  | Cow    |       |
|2  | Dog    |       |
```

I need search a translation in table1 for words in table2.
After I will show table2 in TableView in Java.

How to resolve a problem?

Comment: Do you want to simply _show_ a translation, or do you want to actually update (persist) translation data into `table2` ?

Comment: Second option. In TableView (editable) I will be add translation when is not in the table1

Comment: Everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, Update with JOIN won't work, so you can use the below query to UPDATE the values in to `table2`

```
UPDATE table2
SET namePL = (
        SELECT namePL
        FROM table1
        WHERE nameEN = table2.nameEN
        )
WHERE namePL = ''
```

Comment: Great. And how when I want to update the already added a translation? Then namePL = ' ' it will not work.

Comment: @programmerjavapl Do you mean irrespective of the values are there or not in the `namePL` column, you want to update for all the entries? If so simply remove the `WHERE namePL = ''` condition

Comment: At the time when I'll put tableview translation and I will update in the database whether the above command again to induce embarking? At this moment I have 11000 rows in the database. Is there a possibility that has it all in the database?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table2
SET namePL = (SELECT TOP 1 namePL FROM table1 t1 where t1.nameEN = nameEN)
where namePL = '' or namePL IS NULL
```

Comment: My bad, you need to add LIMIT 1 instead of TOP 1 at the and of nasted query

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".